# Lottie Animation happens every 5 elements in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, lottie

I have a recyclerview with a lot of elements (20+) and a lottie animation in each element. The lottie animation doesn't run until the user taps on it but the problem is that when an animation is tapped the animation happens every 5 elements.

For example if you tap on the 1st element, then element 5, 10, 15,20 all animate.
If you tap on the second then 6,11,16,21 all animate.

Here is my View Holder class:

```
class OutfitViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private final LottieAnimationView animationView;

        private OutfitViewHolder(View view){

            super(view);
         
            animationView = view.findViewById(R.id.wearAgainAnimation);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    wearAgainAnimation();
                }
            });

        }

        private void wearAgainAnimation() {

            final ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f,.5f).setDuration(800);
            animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    animationView.setProgress((Float) animator.getAnimatedValue()) ;
                }
            });

            if (animationView.getProgress() == 0f) {
                animator.start();
            } else {
                animationView.setProgress(0f);
            }

        }
    }
```

I have checked to make sure that only the position of the tapped element is passed to the adapter so I'm not sure why the other elements are also animating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the cache size of the recyclerview to match my list size. I did this when initializing my recyclerview in my class

```
recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(list.size());
```